# simple jquery + javascript not working: add ".has-error" not working and onclick event not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with jQuery 2.1.4 and javascript to do a simple Bootstrap form validation.

I found 3 strange things.

1. I am sure my jQuery code is working in the `onblur` and `onfocus` event of `<input>` elements (as you can try in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/torresdyl/2wuwkbd8/16/)), but I cannot see `.has-error` class style. I have introduced `boostrap.css` etc. in my `<head>` part, of course.
2. `<form-group>` is indenting my paragraph to very end of left side of screen and it hides part of it, I must be using it wrongly but I don't know why.
3. `Cancelar` button is not working. I have tried `<s:url value="/listaReservas.jsp" />` and plain url like in fiddle, no avail. FF complains about `cancelar not defined`.
   Am I allowed to define a pure Javascript function like I did (mixing Javascript with jQuery), or I must bind it like this: `$('#xxxId').click(function(){});`???

Thanks all.

Comment: You mix Bootstrap 2 with Bootstrap 3 classes in CSS..

Comment: So I tried `error` and no avail. You mean this?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms - look at the structure of has-error inputs. First of all - input have to have form-control class, secondly - has-error class must be set to parent of the input. By mixing BS2 with BS3 I mean u use classes like span8 etc. which BS3 does not support.

Comment: thanks! Maybe I shall look into it closer. I have read that "add class to parent" but I guess "form-control is a must-have" is implicit....Well, now the color is working but `.form-control` is making it 100% width, while I'd like it to be less wider...`.form-inline` is not rendering the warning color..

Comment: It will work with `.form-inline` too because `.form-inline` is a parent of `.form-group` :) http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline. Next thing, you can change Bootstrap CSS a little bit and `has-error` will not depend on `form-control`. Or you can set the width of  `.form-control` for example to 150px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.has-error` works but you need to make some changes. First, the class should be added to parent node `form-group` and second, your `<input>` field should have the class `form-control`. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label class="control-label" for="tarjetaId">No. Tarjeta:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="input-xlarge form-control" id="tarjetaId" name="usuarioCompra.numeroTarjeta" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript

```
$("#tarjetaId").blur(function(){
    var cuenta = $("#tarjetaId");
    if (cuenta.val().length != 20){
        cuenta.closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
        $("#comprarButtonId").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        cuenta.closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
    }
});
```

As for `.form-group` giving your layout a negative margin. You are using `.row` as its parent, which also has negative margin. So you are actually applying two layers of negative margins. Having `<div class="row">` is redundant.

Lastly, declare

```
function cancelar() {
    window.location = "/listaReservas.jsp";
};
```

in the global scope, which means outside of `$(document).ready()`. The HTML for the submit button should have `onclick="cancelar()"` instead of `onclick="cancelar"`

Comment: Wouldn't it be `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`?

Comment: Yeah you have corrected all my errors and thanks! Especially the last one, keeps being a myth to me. And the `.form-control` is working but the length is `100%`. Can I shorten it? I tried apply `col-lg-4` but doesn't work.

Comment: And another thing: where can I define variables in jquery script? I tried this: `var cuenta = $("#xxxxId");` and sometimes I get `not defined` error. So where to put these `var`? At first of jquery part or just before the event function, or inside of function?? Another myth....

Comment: @FaithReaper see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes for input width control and also you should have all actions related to DOM inside `$(document).ready()`